# Spotify to audio CD workflow

Tags: audio, music, garageband

I have several Spotify playlists that I would like to burn to audio CDs, after doing some light editing on the song transitions.

I would value some advice about my draft workflow below:

1. Record the Spotify audio to AIFF, using something like [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/)

   - I understand that recording Spotify might not produce the best quality audio. I have a paid Spotify account with high quality streaming, though, so it should be good enough.
   - Is there a better solution than using Audio Hijack here? [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) + …? Quicktime Player only seems to record to M4A, so it does not look like a good option.
2. Edit the AIFF with something like [GarageBand](https://www.apple.com/lae/mac/garageband/), [Reaper](https://www.reaper.fm/) or [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/)

   - Not sure what to use here. I find neither of the software entirely satisfying.
   - I need to burn gapless tracks.
3. Export to… some format that I can easily burn? MP4 with tracks index? APE + CUE?

   - I'm at a loss here, because I do not have a CD/DVD drive on my own (MacBook Air) laptop, and will be using an iMac or PC at work.

Any comments/suggestions would be welcome.